How to Exclude Weekends in Prophet Model for Forex Data?
Question:
I'm working on a time series forecasting project using Prophet to predict foreign exchange (forex) rates, specifically USD to MXN. Since the forex market does not operate on weekends, I need to exclude weekends from both my training data and the future forecast dates. However, I'm still seeing unexpected behavior in the weekly seasonality component, which appears to include weekend effects.
Below is the code I am using:
# Set Seaborn style for cleaner visualizations with grid lines and a white background
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Clean the Data
# Remove any rows in the data where the 'Exchange Rate' column has missing (NaN) values.
# This ensures we only work with complete data.
data_fx = data_fx.dropna(subset=['Exchange Rate'])

# Prepare Data for Prophet Model
# Reset the index of the DataFrame and rename columns to fit Prophet's expected format:
# 'ds' for the date column and 'y' for the target variable, which in this case is 'Exchange Rate'.
prophet_data = data_fx.reset_index()[['index', 'Exchange Rate']].rename(columns={'index': 'ds', 'Exchange Rate': 'y'})

# Remove Weekends from Data
# Add a new column called 'weekday' to indicate the day of the week (0=Monday, 6=Sunday).
# Filter the data to keep only rows where 'weekday' is less than 5, which includes Monday to Friday.
# Drop the 'weekday' column after filtering since it’s no longer needed.
prophet_data['weekday'] = prophet_data['ds'].dt.dayofweek
prophet_data = prophet_data[prophet_data['weekday'] < 5]
prophet_data.drop(columns='weekday', inplace=True)

# Configure and Initialize Prophet Model
# Initialize the Prophet model with specific settings:
# - Disable daily seasonality since Forex does not operate hourly or daily in this dataset context.
# - Enable yearly seasonality to capture any long-term, annual trends.
# - Disable default weekly seasonality since we’ll add a custom one to handle weekdays only.
# - Use a low changepoint prior scale to prevent overfitting on abrupt changes.
model = Prophet(
    daily_seasonality=False,
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    weekly_seasonality=False,
    changepoint_prior_scale=0.05
)

# Add Country-Specific Holidays
# Add holiday effects for both the United States and Mexico, as Forex rates can be influenced
# by holidays in these countries.
model.add_country_holidays(country_name='US')
model.add_country_holidays(country_name='MX')

# Add Custom Weekly Seasonality
# Add a custom weekly seasonality component to model trading patterns across the Monday-Friday period.
# Setting the period to 5 captures the pattern within the business week, while 'fourier_order=3' adds flexibility.
model.add_seasonality(name='custom_weekly', period=5, fourier_order=3)

# Fit the Model
# Train the Prophet model on the prepared data, which excludes weekends and has holidays incorporated.
model.fit(prophet_data)

# Generate Future Forecast Dates
# Create future dates for prediction, generating only business days (Monday to Friday) by using 'B' frequency.
# Setting periods=90 forecasts for the next 90 business days, but this can be adjusted as needed.
future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=90, freq='B')

# Make Predictions
# Use the trained model to predict future exchange rates based on the generated dates.
forecast = model.predict(future_dates)

# Plot the Forecast
# Plot the forecasted exchange rate with confidence intervals.
# The forecasted values are shown in blue, while the actual historical values are in orange.
# Confidence intervals are shown as a shaded area around the forecasted line.
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
sns.lineplot(data=forecast, x='ds', y='yhat', label='Forecasted Exchange Rate', color='blue')
sns.lineplot(data=prophet_data, x='ds', y='y', label='Actual Exchange Rate', color='orange', alpha=0.7)
plt.fill_between(forecast['ds'], forecast['yhat_lower'], forecast['yhat_upper'], color='blue', alpha=0.2)
plt.title("Prophet Model Prediction for USD to MXN Exchange Rate (Excluding Weekends & Holidays)")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Exchange Rate (USD to MXN)")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Plot Forecast Components with Custom Weekly Seasonality
# Plot the components of the forecast, such as trend, yearly seasonality, and custom weekly seasonality.
# Customize the x-axis of the custom weekly component to display only business days (Monday to Friday).
fig = model.plot_components(forecast)
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    if 'custom_weekly' in ax.get_title().lower():
        ax.set_xticks(range(5))
        ax.set_xticklabels(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])
plt.show()

Problem:
Despite filtering out weekends and adding custom weekly seasonality, the weekly seasonality plot still seems to imply weekend effects. I expected Prophet to treat the data as a five-day (Monday-Friday) trading week without weekend influence.
Expected Outcome:

Prophet should ignore weekends entirely, applying weekly seasonality only across business days.

The forecast and forecast component plots should reflect a Monday-Friday pattern only, without any visible weekend impact.

In the custom weekly seasonality component, I expected only five x-axis ticks (Monday to Friday).



Request for Help:
What additional adjustments or configurations are necessary to ensure Prophet fully excludes weekends from both the model and the weekly seasonality component?
